# How to add row percent as new row to dataframe

Tags: r

```
aaa<-data.frame(group=c("A","B"),x1=c(2,8),x2=c(8,2),total=c(10,10),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now I want to compute row percent as new row below freqency row. New dataframe like:

```
group   x1      x2     total
 A       2       8       10
 %       20.00   80.00
 B       8       2
 %       80.00   20.00   10
```

How to do it in R? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In future questions, please show that you've made at least minimal effort to solve the problem yourself.

Here are two ways that use `lapply`. **The second was added later in an edit because it is much simpler that the first, and probably much faster.**

```
> newD <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(aaa)), function(i){
      x1 <- 100*(aaa$x1[i]/aaa$total[i])
      x2 <- 100*(aaa$x2[i]/aaa$total[i])
      rbind(aaa[i, ], c('%', x1, x2, ''))
  }))
> rownames(newD) <- seq(nrow(newD))
> newD
#    group x1 x2 total
# 1      A  2  8    10
# 2      % 20 80      
# 3      B  8  2    10
# 4      % 80 20
```

The second, much better `lapply` method:

```
> pct <- cbind(group = '%', 100*aaa[2:3]/aaa$total, total = '')
> do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(aaa)), function(i){ rbind(aaa[i,], pct[i,]) }))
##    group x1 x2 total
## 1      A  2  8    10
## 2      % 20 80      
## 22     B  8  2    10
## 21     % 80 20
```

**Added, per your comment:** A `for` loop method

```
> x1 <- x2 <- numeric(nrow(aaa))
> rb <- vector('list', nrow(aaa)/2)

> for(i in seq(nrow(aaa))){
    x1[i] <- 100*(aaa$x1[i]/aaa$total[i])
    x2[i] <- 100*(aaa$x2[i]/aaa$total[i])
    rb[[i]] <- rbind(aaa[i, ], c('%', x1[i], x2[i], ''))
  }

> do.call(rbind, rb)
#    group x1 x2 total
# 1      A  2  8    10
# 2      % 20 80      
# 22     B  8  2    10
# 21     % 80 20
```

Comment: @Scriven Thanks. If I want to use loop,How to do it.

Comment: This is a loop.  `lapply` is a looping function (notice the use of `i`).  I could show you a `for` loop method if that's what you're after, but the `apply` functions are the better R way to do looping.

Comment: @Scriven Thanks. I need a for loop method.

Comment: @stata, I've added a `for` loop method